# How to copy "node_modules" using by "webpack-node-externals" to directory with production building?

Tags: node.js, webpack

Consider the full-stack application project with NodeJS back-end.

- `package.json` includes dependencies for **both** front-end (like `vue`, `vuex`, etc.) and back-end (like `body-parser`, `express`, etc.).
- The entry point for frontend (`EntryPoint-FrontEnd.js`) and entry point for backend (`EntryPoint-BackEnd.js`) are being built by different Webpack config; the main differences is usage of [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) and `target: "node"` for back-end.
- The dependencies for frontend are being bundled to `EntryPoint-FrontEnd.js`, but `EntryPoint-BackEnd.js` access to dependencies with `webpack-node-externals`.

[image]

Now: how to copy to `02-ProductionBuild` only those dependencies, which using `EntryPoint-BackEnd.js` via
`webpack-node-externals`?

[image]

I glad if can reach it by `webpack-node-externals`, but if impossible, other tools are welcome.

The basic practice is deploying the full project to host and installing dependencies by `npm install`.
However all that we need for working application in server is `02-ProductionBuild` folder including dependencies for `EntryPoint-BackEnd.js`.

Comment: #1 are you able to improve your source code  management? #2 As a summary your challenge is: How to move specific npm libraries to a custom folder?

Comment: @JRichardsz Thank you for the comment. "are you able to improve your source code management?" - I always able to improve my source code management, but I do it basing on logic and rationales, not on "because everyone doing so". So, constructive criticism is welcome. "As a summary your challenge is: How to move specific npm libraries to a custom folder?" - it so, but the problem is libraries are using the other libraries, so the "specific" is not a part of `dependencies`.

Comment: Not sure what you're question is, but sounds like you're over engineering a problem that doesn't need to exist, why are you trying to share node_modules (I wouldn't but even in my current project at work that does there are no difficulties or weird webpack modules needed)?

Comment: @Dominic `"why are you trying to share node_modules"`, because backend application (`EntryPoint-BackEnd.js`) need a part of them. If we try to bundle them to `EntryPoint-BackEnd.js`, webpack will cast the warnings and possibly application will not work properly. If  begin to google this warnings, "use `webpack-node-externals`" will be recommended.

Answer (score 3):

## Root of problems

- You have one repository to several applications
- You have centralized frontend and backend dependecies in one file: package.json

## Workaround

- Create a npm module capable of create a package.json for each application in your repository. Fictional name: packagify
- Add scripts in your package.json to perform separate builds

```
    {
      "build:frontend" : "packagify ....",
      "build:backend" : "packagify ...."
    }
```

- If you don't want the elegant way of create a new npm library, you can create a simple **packagify.js** file and invoke it from your scripts:

```
    {
      "build:frontend" : "packagify.js ....",
      "build:backend" : "packagify.js ...."
    }
```

## Some Advices

- Don't merge several apps in one source code repository. Each app must have its own source code repository
- Split your current repository in two repositories: One for your frontend and one for your backend
- If each app has its source code repository, you will not have problems to build or deploy them. This is called: **Independent deployment**
- If your organization will grow, you could avoid a new monolithic using microfrontends

## Monolothic Frontend

Since you are using vue, it is sure that your backend is a rest api. So you are close to the classic approach which is opposite to a monolithic application.

One monolithic characteristic:

- frontend and backend source code are in the same repository

[image: web-and-microservice]

But what happen if you put dozens of web features in the same web application? A new monster is born:

[image: monolithic-web]

## Microfrontend & Microservices

As a extremely summary, microfronted is the same as microservice but for frontends

[image: microfrontend-miroservice]

As you should already know, microservices has a lot of advantages. These advantages also applies to microfrontends. One of most important is: **Independent deployment**

## Independent deployment

[image: Independent deployment]

Just as with microservices, independent deployability of micro frontends is key. This reduces the scope of any given deployment, which in turn reduces the associated risk.

In your case,

Check these links;

- https://micro-frontends.org/
- https://medium.com/@tomsoderlund/micro-frontends-a-microservice-approach-to-front-end-web-development-f325ebdadc16
- https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understood that you suggesting me to re-architect my application and you are the opposition of full-stack monolith. I saw that standard Nuxt.JS projects and Laravel projects are full-stack monoliths too. Will you declare that all of these structures are wrong? And please note that this question is not aggression, just the trying to understand your opinion, because I can't re-architecure my applications so simply.

Comment: Why I use the full-stack monolith is thanks to TypeScript, booth front-end and back-end can obey to one business rules now. It's enough reason to keep full-stack monolith structure for me, because business rules has maximal priority and influence on decisions.

Comment: Very nice :D feedback. Can we use a room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223361/monolithics-vs-microfrontend-microservice ?

Comment: The bounty has ended with no direct solutions. With current information the verdict will be: "Webpack does not propose some tools for this problem solving, also as it's impossible to specify in package.json which dependencies are for front-end and which are for the back-end. To reach the desired effect without changing the project structure, we need to create the new tool."